# update of hibernate and spring security failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I would like to update hibernate 3 to 4 and spring 3 to 3.1 and spring security 3 to 3.1 in my application, but when I do this the users with authorities generated using previous versions within database are not usable and the exception

```
 java.io.InvalidClassException GrantedAuthorityImpl local class incompatible
```

occurred when the application want to fetch users' authorities from database. This is the config for entity user:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = GrantedAuthority.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_authorities", schema = "mydb", joinColumns = @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
```

Comment: when I downgrade spring security from 3.1 to 3 everything is ok, do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: no there isn't multiple Spring Security versions and i don't try to hack some class loading problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked differences between [master](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/authority/GrantedAuthorityImpl.java) and [3.0.x](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/3.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/authority/GrantedAuthorityImpl.java) branches. Your problem is in the serialization which is done by Hibernate. Judging on the JPA configuration you are storing serializable POJOs (`GrantedAuthorityImpl`) objects directly in to the database. That is not optimal approach. Better would be to change this to store just collection of strings.

---

**Workaround:** You can put the old `GrantedAuthorityImpl` source in you sources so that the classloader will prefer your version. Then you should be OK with Spring Security 3.1 and still use your approach. However that is from the *hack solutions* category.

Comment: how I can check if there is any serialization of user authorities in the database!

Comment: Just noticed the JPA - Hibernate is serializing it for you. Updated my answer.